# Create a list of years from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` which the head looks like :

```
             total_cost  
date                                                                       
2006-03-04 -1465.052092         
2006-04-04 -1213.508277    
2006-05-04 -1459.290503    
2006-06-04 -1460.119361   
2006-07-04  -772.482609
```

Is there a way to create a list that just has the distinct years that are included in the timeseries. So, for example, if the above timeseries had entries from 2006 to 20012 the list would look like:

```
[2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012]
```

I thought about using a pivot table, but couldn't get the date by year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.index.year.unique().tolist()
```

Demo:

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
             total_cost
date
2006-03-04 -1465.052092
2006-04-04 -1213.508277
2007-05-04 -1459.290503
2008-06-04 -1460.119361
2009-07-04  -772.482609

In [7]: df.index.year.unique().tolist()
Out[7]: [2006, 2007, 2008, 2009]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting the following error:AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'unique'.  Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @Stacey, this is strange... Can you post an output of `type(df.index)` and `df.head().index`

Comment: type(df.index) = <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>   |
df.head().index = DatetimeIndex(['2006-03-04', '2006-04-04', '2006-05-04', '2006-06-04',
               '2006-07-04'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)

Comment: fixed my problem, used:yearList = df.index.year.tolist()
    yearList = list(set(yearList))

Comment: can I do the same for month (returning a unique list of months in the index)?

Comment: @Stacey, sure, `df.index.month.tolist()` - will return a list of month numbers

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my problem, used:

```
yearList = df.index.year.tolist() 
yearList = list(set(yearList))
```

Comment: I think MaxU's solution is better than this. You probably need to update your pandas version to 0.21. Use `pip install --upgrade pandas` and it should work.